How to put Docker Wordpress into development mode?
I am pretty new to both Docker and Wordpress. I wanted to try use both and connect it to Python via REST API. However to do that I need to switch to developer mode.
I went to the documentation there (https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#wp-environment-type) which states that I have to define this variable. I tried doing it through docker-compose.yaml file as follows:
wordpress:
 depends_on:
  - db
 image: wordpress:latest
 restart: always
 ports:
  - '8000:80'
 volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
 environment: 
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: gruny
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: mysql-ps
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
    define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'development' );
 networks:
  - wpsite

The php script sees that and should define it with eval function:
#wp-config.php
if ($configExtra = getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA', '')) {
   eval($configExtra);
}

I confirmed that the $configExtra variable in fact contains the command. However wordpress still doesn't allow me to work with application passwords.
I tried modifying the wp-config.php with define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'development' ); but I see no change.
Then I tried to use plugin called 'Local Development' which should allow me to change this variable, but nothing happens.
I am on this machine
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-21-amd64
Is there something I should do to make this work? Something I should delete or restart or something at all?

you can also activate application password with a plugin. search for wp_is_application_passwords_available in this post : https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/
